# jQuery chaining - why cant I chain this?

Tags: jquery, chaining

Im having an issue with chaining. For example, the following will work

```
$('#myActivityFeed .bv_default_player_pic').attr("src", url);
$('#myActivityFeed. bv_default_player_pic').removeClass().addClass('badge');
```

yet the following will not:

```
$('#myActivityFeed .bv_default_player_pic').attr("src", url).removeClass().addClass('badge');
```

as far as I know, you should be able to chain these events.... any thoughts as to why I cannot?

Comment: what class are you trying to remove?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JSbuu/

Comment: @Ortal, this should work. My best guess is that `url` is `undefined`, so the call to `attr()` is interpreted as its getter form, which is not chainable. Is that the case?

Comment: In your second line of code, the dot is after `myActivityFeed` instead of before `bv_default_player_pic` -- I assume that's not actually in your code?

Comment: correct, yeah, thats not the actual code. I was trying to remove all classes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example should work. [Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/orucuf/3). It shows my Gravatar with a red border around it via class "bv_default_player_pic", inside a div with the `id` value "myActivityFeed". When you click the button, it executes your code (unchanged, literally copied-and-pasted):

```
$('#myActivityFeed .bv_default_player_pic').attr("src", url).removeClass().addClass('badge');
```

...which sets the `src` to be *your* Gravatar, removes all classes, and adds class "badge" (making the border black, with my CSS).

Works just fine. The problem lies elsewhere (is `url` defined?).

Comment: not necessary, className is optional, in which case it removes all the classes. [Check here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: @Arindam: Thanks, I didn't know that but as I was re-reading my answer I thought "...I wonder if it..." and there was your comment. Fixed.

Comment: Sorry, that comment was not meant for your post. Probably a page refresh issue

Comment: @Arindam: No, you were absolutely right, I'd made the same mistake about `removeClass`. Thanks again for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest jQuery version, There is no need to pass a parameter to the removeClass() method.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/AKzdE/) illustrate the above code should be chainable and working even without any parameter passed to removeClass().

From the jQuery [removeClass() docs](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will
>   be removed from the set of matched elements. **If no class names are
>   specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed**.

The only issue I can see in your code is that the variable url may be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass()` with no parameters removes all classes, so why not do this:

```
$('#myActivityFeed .bv_default_player_pic').attr("src", url).attr("class", "badge");
```

Comment: While true, it has nothing to do with the chaining issue the OP was having after the `attr` call.

Answer (score -1):

The `attr` method does not return a jQuery object. Check here.
[attr Api](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Hence you cannot put anything to its end.

Whereas `removeClass` returns a jQuery object. Check here
[removeClass api](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), to which you can continue applying methods of jQuery

Comment: When you're *setting* the attribute as the OP is, it does return the jQuery object: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2 (Not my downvote, and thanks for your comment on my answer.)